# Missing DOI in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, natbib

How do I get to display DOI in the bibliography? I am using `natbib`, and the bibliography template under BibTeX recommended by TeXstudio for an article in a journal is:

```
@Article{ID,
    author = {author},
    title = {title},
    journal = {journal},
    year = {year},
    OPTkey = {key},
    OPTvolume = {volume},
    OPTnumber = {number},
    OPTpages = {pages},
    OPTmonth = {month},
    OPTnote = {note},
    OPTannote = {annote},
}
```

Comment: it depends on the bibliography style if and how such fields are displayed. Many old styles don't support it. With the newer biblatex + biber (instead of natbib and bibtex) it will work always.

Comment: texstudio is just the editor that you are using to write the file The generated output would be the same whichever editor you use so the texstudio tag is not relevant here.

Comment: OK Is there a way to display it with natbib and bibtex, then?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I edited to make the question appropriately general.

Comment: I resolved the problem by switching from apalike to natbib.